# CSS :not selector without combining

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how :not selector works. First of all I try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

p {
    color: #000000;
}

:not(p) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p class="example">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works as ı expect the paragraphs aren't styled and the text in the div and the heading are red. After that I am changing the part in the style tags to this:

```
<style>
    :not(p) {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
```

This time it doesn't work as I expected. Although I want all the elements that are not paragraphs to be red all of them are displayed as red.

Furthermore I am changing the code between the style tags to this:

```
<style>
:not(p.example) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
```

This time I am expecting the elements doesn't fit to "p.example" (h1, div and the second paragraph) to be red but none of the elements are affected.

What do I miss? Shouldn't the examples shown above select all the elements those don't fit to the argument selector? Is there a rule about not using the :not selector alone (e.g not as p:not or h1:not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the previous answers is entirely correct.

In your second case, merely specifying

```
:not(p)
```

colors everything red because it colors the body, and **color is inherited**.

You to **NOT** have to specify, as one answer claims,

```
body :not(p) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

That is almost exactly equivalent to `:not(p)` (which means `*:not(p)`). Nor do you have to specify any other parent such as `.main` as another answer claims.

The third example fails because the argument to `:not` is not a simple selector. The syntax you gave seems to be trying to do is to select everything that is not a `p` with the `example` class. As another respondent pointed out, what you probably meant was everything that **is** a `p` but without the `example` class, for which `p:not(.example)` is correct.

To select elements which are not A and not B (in other words `not (A or B)`, just do

```
:not(A):not(B)
```

For example,

```
:not(h1):not(p)
```

which in this example will apply to the `body` and the `div`. A more realistic example would be to select p's other than those with either of two classes:

```
p:not(.class1):not(.class2)
```

Comment: This. It is about inherited properties. The op isn't doing anything wrong in the first part of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188313/css-not-selector-without-combining#comment42864348_27188356

Answer (score 3):

After @abhitalks comments/feedback. In your first example is nothing wrong, just is related to only inherited properties which will not work. color is inherited, but border is not:

Take a look here [**Full property table**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)

```css
:not(p) {
  color: #f00;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p class="example">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

In you second example:

> Selectors level 3 does not allow anything more than a single [simple
>   selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) within a :not() pseudo-class.

You can change it to:

```css
body :not(.example) {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p class="example">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

Comment: *In your first example the syntax in incorrect...So you have to define E(e.g. body)...* -- Not necessarily. `:not(x)` notation is perfectly fine. It means `*:not(x)`. But, the confusion is that why it works only when a previous style is present (on E or X). See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/m4n07Lt1/ . If you remove the first class, then it stops working. You add any class before it (targetting E or X) and it will work. Does CSS spec say something about implied context?

Comment: And yes, `body :not(p)` is not equivalent to `E:not(x)` because it is not `body:not(p)`. Notice the space. It becomes a descendant as in `body *:not(p)`. So, this must be something to do with descendant/context

Comment: Hmm probably you are right @abhitalks. Still wonder why i can't reproduce to jsfiddle. Is probably something with html structure or whatever

Comment: And I also noticed that the previous style should target the same properties. If the previous class styles `color`, then `:not(p) { font-weight: bold;` won't work.

Comment: @abhitalks it seems it doesn't work for me. What I see is fully yellow background (including background of p elements.) I don't know how it works but it may have selected all the elements again. (My browser is Google Chrome)

Comment: @Zalajbeg: The [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) says `*:not(foo){} will match anything that isn't foo, including html and body*`. So, the yellow background is being applied to at least body which is not p. So, it works that way, yes. And look at developer tools, the style is not applied to `p`.

Comment: Who downvoted this answer, without understanding what's going on? This answer *is very much* useful. Not fair.

Comment: @AlexChar: This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/m4n07Lt1/2/ . It seems some properties get applied and some don't. Please update your answer accordingly that Op isn't doing anything wrong with the first part of the problem. It is related to only inherited properties which will not work. `color` is inherited, but `border` is not.

Comment: Really appreciated your feedback @abhitalks ;) Was afk. Updating now my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The selector `:not(p)` matches *all* elements except `p` elements. This includes the `body` element. When your only style sheet is `:not(p) { color: #ff0000; }`, you thus set all content color red, since the `p` elements inherit color from their parents (here `p`) when no color is set on them directly.

If you want to set the color of content to red except for `p` elements and their descendants, you thus need to be more explicit. A simple way, assuming that this all you want to color, is to set the overall color to red and then override it for `p` elements, letting inner elements inherit color:

```
body { color: red }
p { color: black }
```

The reason why `:not(p.example)` does not work at all is that the operand of [:not](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) must be a simple selector, namely a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class, but not any combination of these; and `p.example` isn’t simple.

You could use the combined selector `:not(p):not(.example)`, which matches any element except `p` elements in class `example`. And this is probably what you want. But the rule won’t work the way want, since here, too, the selector matches the `body` element, among other things, and its color gets inherited by the only element that has not got color specified for it directly. So even in this case, you would need to think otherwise, setting e.g.

```
body { color: red }
p.example { color: black }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems it also corrected the :not(p):not(.example) part of the other answer. But both of your answers clearly answered my question and I accepted the other one as accepted because it made me notice earlier what I am doing wrong. As I am not able to accept two answers I am going to upvote your answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `:not` selector, you should mentioned some parent. Based on that parent only it will work. Otherwise it will select all the elements only.

```
 <div class="main">

  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p class="example">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>

  <div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .main :not(p) {
   color: #ff0000;
 }
```

Also if you don't want to select particular element using `:not` selector you need to use like below.

```
 p:not(.example)
{
  color:green;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b1paw6pd/)

Comment: *you should mentioned some parent* -- this is wrong. See the specs linked to by Alex in the other answer.